# How to add custom fields to customize menu in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add some custom menu points to the customize menu. So the user is able to edit the page much easier.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details? what kind of custom fields you want to add and where? in frontend or in backend?

Comment: I want to ad some fields for custom Text fields and Images.

Comment: You will have to use wp's customize_register hook, and inside it you will have to difine panel, section, settings and control. Refer following link for more detail :

http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer/

Answer (score 1):

In your theme go to the **function.php**

and Code like this

```
function self_customizer_section($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'section_name' , array(
        'title'       => __( 'Self Logo', 'my_theme' ),
        'description' => 'theme general options',
    ));

    /* LOGO */
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'self_logo', array(
        'default' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/mytheme.png'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'self_logo', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Main Logo', 'my_theme' ),
        'section'  => 'section_name',
        'settings' => 'self_logo',
    )));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'self_customizer_section');
```

For more detail you can follow the below link he made the awesome tutorial on that question

See in continuation.

here is the link

[Wordpress Theme Customization API Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XloM1F5M2fU)